# Gulp task with gulp-run won't stop, won't exit

Tags: gulp

The following is the gulp task I use to optimize my RequireJs project

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
//var requirejsOptimize = require('gulp-requirejs-optimize');
var run = require('gulp-run');
var exit = require('gulp-exit');

gulp.task('optimize', function(){
    return run('node r.js -o build.js').exec()
    .on('end', () => {
          console.log('Completed');
        })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output'))
    .pipe(exit());
});
```

It works fine and does what it's meant to do. ie. optimize the project. A new folder containing the optimized project is created. But my problem is that the only thing I see on screen is this

```
 Starting 'optimize'...
```

I don't see the console log, nor does the program exit.

Comment: Just drop the `.pipe(exit())`.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung, I brought in gulp-exit as the task wouldn't exit. Now it won't exit even with gulp-exit. To debug, I tried adding pipe.on("end",fn()) listener. The console.log is not printing. I think this means run().exec() i not ending..